# Problemas con la validacion de una contraseña bycript

Tags: php, encriptación

Estoy creando un login con la pass encriptada con bycrpt
y me genera bien el codigo encriptado, pero al querer validarlo, no me devuelve ningun mensaje ni nada, por lo que la validacion no se ejecuta o algo asi

```
if (password_verify($pass, $hash)){
    $pass_new = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    // reemplazo la antigua pass por $pass_new en la base de datos
    $status = 'SUCCESS';
    $msj = 'Todo ok';
}else{
    $status = "Error";
    $errorNum = 409;
    $msj = "Contraseña incorrecta";
}
$return = array('status' => $status, 'href' => $href, 'errorNum' => $errorNum, 'msj' => $msj);
die(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: Tu código devuelve algo sólo en caso de error. Prueba a poner algo así en la 1ª parte del `if`: **`$return=array('status'=>'Todo OK');`**

Comment: No termino de entender la lógica. Comparas el $pass contra el $hash y si son iguales, vuelves a generar el hash?
Si son distintos cargas las variables para informar el error, informas el error y termina.
Nunca informas nada si son correctos, la carga de variables esta solo en el false.
Creo q el problema esta por ahí.
Seria necesario mas informacion para enteder el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano no creo necesario que retorne algo ya que solo busco que inserte la nueva contraseña y cree los datos de session, luego de eso, una vez con los datos de session creados, la pagina se recargara con la session iniciada.

Comment: @Armage Claro, comparo el pass ingresado con un $hash, que vendria a ser la contraseña encriptada en la base de datos, si son iguales, se crea una clave completamente nueva y se actualiza la que esta en la base de datos.
Mi problema es que por algun motivo no me retorna nada esa validacion
¿Motivo? aun no lo se
y busco algo de informacion aqui, tal vez una solucion u otras opciones de encriptacion

Comment: Tú decías que *no me devuelve ningun mensaje ni nada...* y te expliqué que no había nada que se devolviera en caso de éxito. Viendo que modificaste el `if`, ¿ahora tampoco devuelve nada?  ¿Ese es todo el código? Porque ahora mencionas otras cosas que antes no mencionabas. Por favor explica el contexto completo para poder ayudarte. No estamos delante de tu pantalla para saber lo que tienes.

Comment: Actualmente las claves en almacenadas en base de datos ¿Cómo han sido encriptadas?

Comment: @Xerif fueron encriptadas de la mismanera,
Basicamente mostre por consola una clave encritada y la agregue como contraseña, para que fuera el mismo formato y se pudiera comparar